# What is the perfect configuration for a Elasticsearch cluster designed for High Availiability?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to design a elasticsearch cluster for high availability.

What is the ideal configuration ( nodes numbers, nodes roles, node configurations, etc ) for elasticsearch? What parameters ( workload, how much search and writes per second, etc ) do I have to consider?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I responded on your Discuss topic with a similar answer

it depends
what's your SLAs around indexing/query response times? what's your uptime requirements? what's your budget? what's your data source? what's your expected indexing and query work load?